# Как красиво превратить csv в датасет?

Tags: python

Дано файл , 12-ть колонок .Надо превратить его в красивый датасет , вида {"name":{'second':'some1':3,'some2':23}} , у меня есть решение , но оно топорное , может кто-то знает как красиво сделать ? 
Кусочек самого датасета :
roduct_ID,Gender,Age,Occupation,City_Category,Stay_In_Current_City_Years,Marital_Status,Product_Category_1,Product_Category_2,Product_Category_3,Purchase
1000001,P00069042,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,3,,,8370
1000001,P00248942,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,1,6,14,15200
1000001,P00087842,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,12,,,1422
1000001,P00085442,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,12,14,,1057
1000002,P00285442,M,55+,16,C,4+,0,8,,,7969
1000003,P00193542,M,26-35,15,A,3,0,1,2,,15227
1000004,P00184942,M,46-50,7,B,2,1,1,8,17,19215
1000004,P00346142,M,46-50,7,B,2,1,1,15,,15854
1000004,P0097242,M,46-50,7,B,2,1,1,16,,15686
1000005,P00274942,M,26-35,20,A,1,1,8,,,7871
1000005,P00251242,M,26-35,20,A,1,1,5,11,,5254
1000005,P00014542,M,26-35,20,A,1,1,8,,,3957
1000005,P00031342,M,26-35,20,A,1,1,8,,,6073
1000005,P00145042,M,26-35,20,A,1,1,1,2,5,15665
1000006,P00231342,F,51-55,9,A,1,0,5,8,14,5378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По первому запросу в гугл "csv to dict python" есть самое простое решение - использовать модуль csv и его метод csv.DictReader, который создаёт готовый к использованию dict из csv.